# How to find the value of the recursive formula as n approaches Infinity

Tags: calculus

The formula is $a_{n+1}=a_n\times(2-11a_n)$,start from $a_n=0.1$,and $n$ approaches Infinity.

I try to use monotonic sequence theorem,but I fail to find the bound and show whether the function is increasing or decreasing.

Comment: If it converges then it converges to one of the solutions of $x=x(2-11x)$

Comment: What do you want ? To prove that the sequence converges/diverges, or to find a closed form for the general term ?

Comment: I want to find a(n) as n approaches Infinity.

Comment: The answer is 1/11

Answer (score 2):

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ by
$$f(x)=x(2-11x)$$

The function $f$ is differentiable and $$f'(x)=2-22x$$
Therefore, $f'(x) \geq 0$ if and only if $x \leq \frac{1}{11}$, so $f$ increases on $(-\infty, \frac{1}{11}]$ and decreases on $[\frac{1}{11}, +\infty)$. Hence it has a maximum at $x = \frac{1}{11}$, and the value at this maximum is $f(\frac{1}{11})=\frac{1}{11}$.

Because $a_0= 0.1$, then $a_1 = f(0.1)=0.09$ belongs to $(-\infty, \frac{1}{11}]$ which is a stable interval for $f$ ; because $f$ is increasing on this interval, the sequence is monotonous after $a_1$. Moreover, $a_2 = f(0.09)=0.0909 > a_1$, so the sequence is increasing after $a_1$. Because it is bounded above by $\frac{1}{11}$, it converges.

The limit is the only fixed point of $f$ in $(0.09, \frac{1}{11}]$, which is $\frac{1}{11}$ itself.

Comment: Thank you,but I can't figure out why it must bounded above by 1/11.

Comment: Because $(-\infty, \frac{1}{11}]$ is a stable interval for $f$, hence all the terms of the sequence (after $a_1$) belong to this interval.